# React-Native: Issue with rending JSON object

Tags: android, json, fetch, react-native

Facing React Native issue of rendering fetched JSON from API.

```
// Code used to fetch Json
const appSettingsApiCall = await state = {
        app_settings: null,

        loading: true
    }
    async componentDidMount() {

        try {
            //Assign the promise unresolved first then get the data using the json method.
            // AppSettings Information

            const appSettingsApiCall = await fetch('URL/api/app_settings');
            const appSettings = await countyListApiCall.json();

            this.setState({ app_settings: appSettings.data, loading: false});
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
        }
    }

// Saved in state 
this.setState({ app_settings: appSettings.data });
Receiving following JSON.
```

> {"success":true,"data":{"_token":"7NQvC2AFzdV3OTIdB1cFFe5I88fYTvWchk9d3Xfl","heroImage":"http://test/storage/photos/1/hero.png","heroText":"We Protect Your Profits</h1>\r\n\r\n
>
> Bottom line control, top line growth</p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\t
>
> POS Solutions made specifically for the hospitality industry</li>\r\n\t
>
> 24/7 Local Support</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n","buttonText":"Get a Free POS Evaluation","buttonLink":"https://offers.test.com/free-pos-consultation","shopLink":"test.com","trainingLink":"https://offers.test.com/help-videos","emergancyText":"","emergancyPhone":"234234324324","websiteLink":"https://www.test.com/","facebookLink":"https://www.facebook.com/PinnaclePOS","instagramLink":"https://www.instagram.com/test/","linkdinLink":"https://www.linkedin.com/company/test"},"message":"Users"}

I have not multiple values for this JSON. You can see details

Fetching on front end view

```
const { app_settings } = this.state;
```

On View side using following code

```
<Image source={app_settings.heroImage} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
```

Data fetched properly as I added condition if it's null that display Null View. It's going to 2nd condition it means values are coming. My finding is issue on View Side rest of everyhting looks good.

React Native issue of not showing JSON result fetched from API.

```
async componentDidMount() {

        try {
            //Assign the promise unresolved first then get the data using the json method.
            // AppSettings Information

            const appSettingsApiCall = await fetch('http://www.test.com/api/app_settings');
            const appSettings = await countyListApiCall.json();

            this.setState({ app_settings: appSettings.data, loading: false});
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `countyListApiCall` instead of `appSettingsApiCall` when transposing the response to json.

Comment: Thanks, Buddy. My Mistake